With mpc.el, can I search for filenames?
On the command line, I can search for filenames, like
mpc search filename foo

Can mpc.el also do that? Whenever I search, I seem to only be able to search for metadata.

Apparently not. Check also this or read the comments at the beginning of mpc.el file.
